# ChartJS line chart starts in center of chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In this JSFiddle example,

https://jsfiddle.net/01eks6dh/

The line for abc123.com starts on 2019-11-01 but the chart's xAxis starts on 2019-09-01. There is no data for abc123.com before 2019-11-01 so I understand why it starts there. Is there anyway to complete the line so that it starts at 2019-09-01 WITHOUT ADDING ZERO VALUE TO THE DATASET? Is there any way to add an option to it? Or some callback/override?

```
{
    type: 'line',
        data: {
        "labels": [],
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "label": "abc123.com",
                    "data": [
                        { "t": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 1537567 },
                        { "t": "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 627 },
                        { "t": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 22 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "test345.com",
                    "data": [
                        { "t": "2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 37923 },
                        { "t": "2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 173744 },
                        { "t": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 426863 },
                        { "t": "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 136497 },
                        { "t": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "y": 241620 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'll',
                        hour: 'll hA',
                    },
                },
            }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are infinite ways to complete the line. Which one would you like? Can you upload a (hand-drawn) image of your desired outcome?

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/qudo7rzh vs this https://jsfiddle.net/86pnrb4x. I added a bunch of ZERO data-points to it to create the desired affect, but I am looking for way to do it without adding ZERO data-points. You know, now that I look at it, this graph is totally misleading. It makes it look like the number event (y-axis) slowly trended down over time, but they actually completely dropped until 2019-12-01.

Comment: If you don't want to add the points in your data, you can add them dynamically in the code that get that data.